# Index match match/vlookup in VBA

Tags: vba, match, vlookup

I have an Excel document with two different Sheets. Sheet 2 has columns header names and rows header names. Sheet 1 has some of these columns with exact header names and rows header names but it's filled with data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQOpi.png), [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHi2b.png)

I want to make a macro that will look through all the column/rows headers in Sheet 1 and find their corresponding match in Sheet2. When the match is found, I need to copy the entry of the Sheet column/row header into the matching header of sheet2. Some entries in Sheet2 will not have matches and will remain blank.
I want it to look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRNxr.png)

This is my code so far, it is working for the column headers but I don't know how to add for row headers as well. Any help is welcomed :)

```
Sub CopyData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long, header As Range, foundHeader As Range, lCol As Long, srcWS As Worksheet, desWS As Worksheet
    Set srcWS = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set desWS = Sheets("Sheet2")
    LastRow = srcWS.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lCol = desWS.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For Each header In desWS.Range(desWS.Cells(3, 2), desWS.Cells(3, lCol))
        Set foundHeader = srcWS.Rows(2).Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not foundHeader Is Nothing Then
            srcWS.Range(srcWS.Cells(3, foundHeader.Column), srcWS.Cells(LastRow, foundHeader.Column)).Copy desWS.Cells(4, header.Column)
        End If
    Next header
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you want to copy on Sheet2 cells that have matching headers (top and left) with Sheet1 ?

Comment: @Vincent Exactly. Now it's matching only top header :)

Comment: See my answer below. I can eventually write a peace of code if you don't see how to do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best solution might to set 2 ranges, each taking values from tables in Sheet1 and Sheet2. Let's call them `rgSrcTable` and `rgDestTable`. Then you need to loop using `For Each` through each range and compare top and left headers, and when you find a match, copy the value of the cell in `rgSrcTable` to the cell in `rgDestTable`.

**Edit: Code sample.** Feel free to adapt ranges to your needs. Since this routine used `Range.Value` property, you can filter any data (string, numbers, etc.)

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyDataWithFilter()
    Dim iRowHeader As Integer, iColHeader As Integer
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range, celSrc As Range, celDest As Range
    
    iRowHeader = 2
    iColHeader = 1
    With ThisWorkbook
        ' Set source and destination ranges. Modify ranges according to your needs
        Set rngSrc = .Worksheets("shtSrc").Range("$B$3:$E$5")
        Set rngDest = .Worksheets("shtDest").Range("$B$3:$E$5")
        
        ' Loop through source range and dest range
        For Each celDest In rngDest
            For Each celSrc In rngSrc
            
                ' Compare top headers and left headers respectively. If matching, copy the value in destination table.
                If .Worksheets("shtSrc").Cells(celSrc.Row, iColHeader).Value = .Worksheets("shtDest").Cells(celDest.Row, iColHeader).Value And _
                   .Worksheets("shtSrc").Cells(iRowHeader, celSrc.Column).Value = .Worksheets("shtDest").Cells(iRowHeader, celDest.Column).Value Then
                   celDest.Value = celSrc.Value
                End If
            Next celSrc
        Next celDest
    End With
End Sub
```

Result:

[image: Source table]

[image: Destination table]

Comment: I would really appreciate an example to apply for my code. Thank you!

Comment: @Dodoi Code added :)

Comment: Hello! Those sheets are in different workbooks. In this case should I delete `With ThisWorkbook ` and when I set up the range I just have to put the workbook name in front of the worksheet, like this? `Set rngSrc = Workbooks("Excel report.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("$C$7:$G$30")`

Comment: Exactly. Since you'll need to reference both workbooks (and worksheets), you could also create 2 variables ```shtSrc = Workbook("name of source workbook").Worksheets("name of source worksheet")``` and ```shtDest``` (same formula but for destination). This way you only need to call ```shtSrc``` or ```shtDest``` instead of the heavy coding and you can easily adapt in case workbooks' name or worksheets' name changes.

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you so much @Vincent

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in Range.Consolidate method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.consolidate):
(**Edit2**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConsolidateThis()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, addr As String
    With ThisWorkbook
        ' determine source and destination ranges
        Set rng1 = getTableRange(.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2"))
        Set rng2 = getTableRange(.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A3"))
        
        ' make full address of consolidated range like "'[Consolidate.xlsm]Sheet1'!R3C1:R6C5"
        addr = "'[" & .Name & "]" & rng1.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng1.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
        
        ' do consolidation
        rng2.Consolidate Sources:=Array(addr), Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True
    End With
End Sub

' Returns the range that starts with the top left corner cell and is bounded
' on the right and bottom by empty cells
Function getTableRange(LeftTopCornerCell As Range) As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rightEdge As Long, downEdge As Long
    With LeftTopCornerCell(1)
        Set ws = .Parent
        rightEdge = ws.Cells(.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        downEdge = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    Set getTableRange = ws.Range(LeftTopCornerCell(1), ws.Cells(downEdge, rightEdge))
End Function
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know why but it replaces row header from Sheet2 with header from Sheet1. So Sheet2 has the same (abc abcd **abcde** dbc) and this header moves on the second row (B2:E2).

Comment: Most likely, the ranges `rng1` and `rng2` were defined incorrectly. I used the `Range.CurrentRegion` property to determine source and destination ranges, it is a range bounded by any combination of blank rows and blank columns (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion). You can define the `rng1` and `rng2`  in another way. Check them with `Debug.Print rng1.Address` and ``Debug.Print rng2.Address`` before doing consolidation

Comment: @Dodoi see Edit2 version. Added `getTableRange` functon for the range definition

Comment: It is working now. Thank you so much and sorry for bothering you! I was just wondering how can I replace the content, not delete it? And if I have text values, not just numeric, should I add Paste Special?

Comment: With text data, this approach will not work, you will need to write other code