# Vlookup equivalent in VBA for DATE AND TIME with APROXIMATE MATCH

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the summary:
[image: this is what I want]
[image: this is what I have achieved so far]

Here is the problem in details:

I have a high school class time table saved in a worksheet named **shtSrc**.

The time table looks like this:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Start Time | End Time | Day | Period | Subject | Teacher |
| 2 | 8:20:00 AM | 9:10:00 AM | Sunday | 1 | GEOGRAPHY | JE |
| 3 | 9:10:00 AM | 10:00:00 AM | Sunday | 2 | HISTORY | SU |
| 4 | 10:00:00 AM | 10:40:00 AM | Sunday | 3 | BUSINESS | SA |
| 5 | 10:40:00 AM | 11:40:00 AM | Sunday | 4 | BREAK |  |
| 6 | 11:40:00 AM | 12:30:00 PM | Sunday | 5 | MATHS | SH |
| 7 | 12:30:00 PM | 1:30:00 PM | Sunday | 6 | SCIENCE | JU |
| 8 | 1:30:00 PM | 8:20:00 PM | Sunday | 7 | EXTRA CLASS |  |
| 9 | 8:20:00 AM | 9:10:00 AM | Monday | 1 | BUSINESS | SA |
| 10 | 9:10:00 AM | 10:00:00 AM | Monday | 2 | SCIENCE | SU |
| 11 | 10:00:00 AM | 10:40:00 AM | Monday | 3 | HISTORY | RE |
| 12 | 10:40:00 AM | 11:40:00 AM | Monday | 4 | BREAK |  |
| 13 | 11:40:00 AM | 12:30:00 PM | Monday | 5 | MATHS | SH |
| 14 | 12:30:00 PM | 1:30:00 PM | Monday | 6 | GEOGRAPHY | RE |
| 15 | 1:30:00 PM | 8:20:00 PM | Monday | 7 | EXTRA CLASS |  |
| 16 | 8:20:00 AM | 9:10:00 AM | Tuesday | 1 | BUSINESS | SA |
| 17 | 9:10:00 AM | 10:00:00 AM | Tuesday | 2 | HISTORY | SU |
| 18 | 10:00:00 AM | 10:40:00 AM | Tuesday | 3 | GEOGRAPHY | JE |
| 19 | 10:40:00 AM | 11:40:00 AM | Tuesday | 4 | BREAK |  |
| 20 | 11:40:00 AM | 12:30:00 PM | Tuesday | 5 | MATHS | SH |
| 21 | 12:30:00 PM | 1:30:00 PM | Tuesday | 6 | SCIENCE | JU |
| 22 | 1:30:00 PM | 8:20:00 PM | Tuesday | 7 | EXTRA CLASS |  |

**Here, the schedule is demonstrated for 3 working days. 7 time slots per day. Working hours 8:20 AM to 8:20 PM. The order of subjects taught on a day is not the same everyday.**

**Classes may start on time, or 10-15 minutes later.** The date and time when a class actually started was recorded in column A of a worksheet named  **shtDest**. The sheet looks like this:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Entry date and time | Entry date | Entry day | Entry time | Start Time | Period | Subject | Teacher |
| 2 | 1/1/2021 8:25 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 1/3/2021 9:25 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 1/3/2021 10:20 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | 1/4/2021 13:30 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | 1/5/2021 0:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I filled up rest of the table using some excel formula and some VBA. The **shtDest** finally looked like this:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Entry date and time | Entry date | Entry day | Entry time | Start Time | Period | Subject | Teacher |
| 2 | 1/1/2021 8:25 | 1/1/2021 | Friday | 8:25 AM |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 1/3/2021 9:25 | 1/3/2021 | Sunday | 9:25 AM | 9:10:00 AM | 2 | HISTORY | SU |
| 4 | 1/3/2021 10:20 | 1/3/2021 | Sunday | 10:20 AM | 10:00:00 AM | 3 | BUSINESS | SA |
| 5 | 1/4/2021 13:30 | 1/4/2021 | Monday | 1:30 PM | 1:30:00 PM | 7 | EXTRA CLASS |  |
| 6 | 1/5/2021 0:00 | 1/5/2021 | Tuesday | 12:00 AM |  |  |  |  |

The formula I used in **E2** to get the start time:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,IF(shtSrc!$C$2:$C$22=C2,shtSrc!$A$2:$F$22,""),1,TRUE),"")
```

For **F2:H6**, I used a Vlookup alternative with VBA. Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub VlookupAlternative()
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range, celSrc As Range, celDest As Range
    

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set rngSrc = .Worksheets("shtSrc").Range("$A$1:$F$22")
        Set rngDest = .Worksheets("shtDest").Range("$F$2:$H$6")
        
        ' Compare top headers and left headers respectively. If matching, copy the value in destination table.
        For Each celDest In rngDest
            For Each celSrc In rngSrc
            
'         ***   This is the line I want as first line in the IF statement:
'         ***   If .Worksheets("shtSrc").Cells(celSrc.Row, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(Format(CLng(CDate(.Worksheets("shtDest").Cells(celDest.Row, 1).Value)), "h:mm:ss AM/PM"), rngSrc, 1, True) And _

                If .Worksheets("shtSrc").Cells(celSrc.Row, 1).Value = .Worksheets("shtDest").Cells(celDest.Row, 5).Value And _
                        .Worksheets("shtSrc").Cells(celSrc.Row, 3).Value = Format(.Worksheets("shtDest").Cells(celDest.Row, 1).Value, "DDDD") And _
                        .Worksheets("shtSrc").Cells(1, celSrc.Column).Value = .Worksheets("shtDest").Cells(1, celDest.Column).Value Then
                    celDest.Value = celSrc.Value
                End If
            Next celSrc
        Next celDest
    End With
End Sub
```

For this code I am thankful to this link: [Index match match/vlookup in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67890930/index-match-match-vlookup-in-vba/67891165#67891165)

**The main issue is:**

To run this code, I have to provide EXACT START TIME in column E. And to get the values in column E, I need 3 helper columns: B, C, D. **I tried using `Application.VLookup` for column E but I failed with "Type Mismatch" Error.**

When I tried replacing the first line of the IF statement

```
If .Worksheets("shtSrc").Cells(celSrc.Row, 1).Value = .Worksheets("shtDest").Cells(celDest.Row, 5).Value And _
```

with this line

```
If .Worksheets("shtSrc").Cells(celSrc.Row, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(Format(CLng(CDate(.Worksheets("shtDest").Cells(celDest.Row, 1).Value)), "h:mm:ss AM/PM"), rngSrc, 1, True) And _
```

I got a "Type Mismatch" error.

**I want to:**

I want to achieve the same output **without any formula, without any helper columns, using only VBA**. Is approximate match possible using **arrays or dictionaries**? My shtSrc has 20,000+ entries. Can you suggest any way alternative to VLOOKUP WITH APPROXIMATE MATCH without using `Application.VLookup`?

Answer (score 0):

The **Vlookup statement** I wanted to include finally worked when I converted **Timevalue to Double**.
The Vlookup statement now is:

```
        If .Worksheets("shtSrc").Cells(celSrc.Row, 1).Value = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(CDbl(TimeValue(.Worksheets("shtDest").Cells(celDest.Row, 1).Value)), rngSrc, 1, True), "") And _
```

With a dynamic range selection using last row and last column, **The final VBA code is:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub VlookupAlternative()
    
    Const INPUT_SHT = "shtSrc"
    Const OUTPUT_SHT = "shtDest"
    
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsIn As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range, celSrc As Range, celDest As Range
    Dim rLastIn As Long, cLastIn As Long
    Dim rLastOut As Long, cLastOut As Long

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsIn = wb.Sheets(INPUT_SHT)
    Set wsOut = wb.Sheets(OUTPUT_SHT)
    
    
    rLastIn = lastRow(wsIn)
    cLastIn = LastCol(wsIn)
    
    rLastOut = lastRow(wsOut)
    cLastOut = LastCol(wsOut)
    
    With wb

        Set rngSrc = wsIn.Range("$A$2:$F$" & rLastIn)
        Set rngDest = wsOut.Range("$B$2:$D$" & rLastOut)
        
        
        ' Compare top headers and left headers respectively. If matching, copy the value in destination table.
        For Each celDest In rngDest
            For Each celSrc In rngSrc
                If wsIn.Cells(celSrc.Row, 1).Value = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(CDbl(TimeValue(wsOut.Cells(celDest.Row, 1).Value)), rngSrc, 1, True), "") And _
                    wsIn.Cells(celSrc.Row, 3).Value = Format(wsOut.Cells(celDest.Row, 1).Value, "DDDD") And _
                    wsIn.Cells(1, celSrc.Column).Value = wsOut.Cells(1, celDest.Column).Value Then
                    celDest.Value = celSrc.Value
                End If
            Next celSrc
        Next celDest
    End With
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Function lastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    lastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

**Final output:**

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Entry date and time | Period | Subject | Teacher |
| 2 | 1/1/2021 8:25 |  |  |  |
| 3 | 1/3/2021 9:25 | 2 | HISTORY | SU |
| 4 | 1/3/2021 10:20 | 3 | BUSINESS | SA |
| 5 | 1/4/2021 13:30 | 7 | EXTRA CLASS |  |
| 6 | 1/5/2021 0:00 |  |  |  |